# Attribute is not identical to the right hand side value of a preceding attribute assignment operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question might superficially look like a duplicate,
but it is *not* about the usual [mutable surprise](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) with lists.

More details later, but in a nutshell, just after

```
self.facts = facts
print("facts: ", id(facts))
print("self.facts: ", id(self.facts))
```

sometimes `self.facts` and `facts` were not identical.

The app is single-threaded, and the difference lasts,
so it does *not* seem to be a race condition or buffer delay.

I did clear the cache:
`find . -name "*.pyc" -delete`

I tried to come up with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),
but could not reproduce the bug. Here is an attempt.

```
class Fact():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == self.b

facts1 = [Fact(1), Fact(2), Fact(3)]
id(facts1)
facts2 = facts1
id(facts2)
# same as facts1
facts3 = [Fact(1), Fact(2), Fact(3)]
id(facts3)
facts2 = facts3
id(facts2)
# same as fact3, as it should
```

A snapshot and steps to reproduce can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/issues/381).

As soon as the `__eq__` was [expanded](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/pull/382/commits/9dc0d96a11077ba3cc18f3c9316c5906bc5084ca) to check also fields that did change, both `facts` and `self.facts` held elements that were equal (in the sense of `__eq__`), so good enough, but not identical, which is still weird.

Is that something known ? here is my python version:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 31 2018, 19:45:04) [GCC] on linux
on openSUSE Leap 15.0
```

What could be happening ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `self.a = a` instead of `a = a`?

Comment: @Bazingaa good catch. Thanks ! Edited. Bug still not reproducible with it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "identical"?

Comment: @ekhumoro `id(self.facts) == id(facts)`

Comment: @ederag Many things could cause this but without the relevant code that generates `self` it's hard to pinpoint. For example `facts` could be a `property` and then do all sorts of things when you assign `self.facts = facts`. So you basically need to show the code of the class that `self` corresponds to.

Comment: @ederag I don't see how anyone can answer this unless you provide a genuine mcve.

Comment: @a_guest yes, any descriptor could potentially be causing all sorts of side-effects for `self.a = a`. We can only speculate about that, though.

Comment: @ekhumoro A link to the snapshot is not good enough, and an mcve is required, agreed, but none found yet. Initially I was hoping for "hey, that's bug #..." (although I did search in https://bugs.python.org/). Conversely, answers with mcve displaying the symptoms would be very good, and interesting for a larger audience too ? I'll try to rephrase the question and give an example of the symptomatic output.

Comment: @a_guest Thanks for the pointer. There are no properties, apparently. The class is defined [there](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/blob/3245adbdbd85c7b4ee6c5ac93a0cf05132555968/src/hamster/widgets/facttree.py#L184-556). But I would upvote an answer with an mcve showing how a `property` might trigger the symptom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such behavior can be caused by many things, all of which control *how* an object's attributes are accessed.
In that sense `self.x = y` is very much different from `x = y`. The former attempts to set the attribute `"x"` with `y`
on the object `self` while the latter binds the name `"x"` to the object `y` in the local scope.

## Descriptors

[Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) can control how attributes are
dealt with by defining the special methods `__get__`, `__set__`, `__delete__`. An example:

```
from copy import copy

class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        return copy(self.list_obj)  # Return a copy -> id changes.

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.list_obj = copy(val)  # Store a copy -> id changes.

class Foo:
    facts = Descriptor()

facts = [1, 2, 3]
obj = Foo()
obj.facts = facts
assert id(obj.facts) != id(facts)  # ids are different.
```

### Properties

[`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) is probably one of the most prominent usage scenarios for
data descriptors. Hence the workings are very similar:

```
from copy import copy

class Foo:
    @property
    def facts(self):
        return copy(self._facts)  # Return a copy -> id changes.

    @facts.setter
    def facts(self, val):
        self._facts = copy(val)  # Store a copy -> id changes.

facts = [1, 2, 3]
obj = Foo()
obj.facts = facts
assert id(obj.facts) != id(facts)  # ids are different.
```

## `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`

By defining the methods [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) and
[`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) a class can control the attribute access
of its instances. For example:

```
from copy import copy

class Foo:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return copy(super().__getattr__(name))  # Return a copy -> id changes.

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        super().__setattr__(name, copy(val))  # Store a copy -> id changes.

facts = [1, 2, 3]
obj = Foo()
obj.facts = facts
assert id(obj.facts) != id(facts)  # ids are different.
```

## How can I find out what intercepts the attribute access?

You can check `type(obj).facts` in order to find out whether `facts` is defined to be a descriptor.
Similarly you can check `type(obj).__(get|set)attr__` to see whether *any* of the base classes defines
this special method. Worth noting here is that any of the above described methods also works if it is defined
on any of the classes sitting in the method resolution order (`__mro__`, i.e. the parent classes).
So you would need to check for example:

```
any('__getattr__' in vars(cls) for cls in type(obj).__mro__)
```

## The OP's specific example

The class you linked inherits from
[this class](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/blob/3245adbdbd85c7b4ee6c5ac93a0cf05132555968/src/hamster/lib/graphics.py#L1712) which defines
[`__setattr__`](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/blob/3245adbdbd85c7b4ee6c5ac93a0cf05132555968/src/hamster/lib/graphics.py#L1861)
in a way that it checks
for *equality* (`==`; not identity (`is`)) with an existing value and returns if they compare equal.
That means especially if you have two lists that compare equal, i.e. `self.facts == facts`, then
doing `self.facts = facts` will just return and not set the attribute. Hence nothing changed
and the two objects (`self.facts` and `facts`) are still distinct. The code basically comes down to this:

```
class Foo:
    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        if self.__dict__.get(name, None) == val:  # Could also use `getattr(self, name, None)`.
            return
        super().__setattr__(name, val)

facts = [1, 2, 3]
obj = Foo()
obj.facts = [1, 2, 3]
assert obj.facts == facts          # The two lists compare equal,
obj.facts = facts                  # hence nothing will happen here,
assert obj.facts == facts          # they still compare equal,
assert id(obj.facts) != id(facts)  # but are still two distinct objects.
```

Comment: Wow. I did not expect to see a believable explanation, but here it is anyway. Nice sleuthing, +1

Comment: Thanks for the masterpiece ! Perfect explanations both to debug the general case and to understand my specific example.